# UITextFields not displaying in struct, how to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview

I am trying to have a submission form of some type on my app, but I cannot place UItextfields for some reason. I have them declared in the beginning of this struct, but when it comes to displaying I get the error:

"Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols"

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

/// Shows a list of inspiring quotes/bio
struct FeatureView: View {
    
    @State private var userEmail: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x:10, y:320, width:300.00, height:30.00))
    
    private var instagramName: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x:10, y:320, width:300.00, height:30.00))
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Get Featured").font(.largeTitle).bold()
                    Spacer()
                    Text("1. Submit your information below")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("2. On the 1st and 14th we choose a new account to feature")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("3. Get notified by e-mail if your account is chosen!")
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
                userEmail.placeholder = "email"
                userEmail.addSubview(userEmail)
            }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))
            
        }
    }
}
```

I am just trying to get an email field displayed and editable for now, but eventually I want 5-6 different fields that all take information that I can eventually have the user submit

Comment: How about using a SwiftUI `TextField` instead of trying to mix the two different interface styles?

Comment: Just a minor side note: You don't need to import SwiftUI AND UIKit because SwiftUI includes UIKit already...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `TextField`. If you want to use `UIKit`, you have to wrap `UITextField` into `UIViewRepresentable`.

Here is how you can use `TextField`, you need to create two `@State` properties to track the text for each `TextField`:

```
import SwiftUI

/// Shows a list of inspiring quotes/bio
struct FeatureView: View {

    @State private var emailText: String = ""
    @State private var instagramNameText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Get Featured").font(.largeTitle).bold()
                    Spacer()
                    Text("1. Submit your information below")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("2. On the 1st and 14th we choose a new account to feature")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("3. Get notified by e-mail if your account is chosen!")
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))

            VStack {
                TextField("Email", text: $emailText)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 30)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                TextField("Instagram name", text: $instagramNameText)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 30)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how you wrap it with `UIViewRepresentable` to use `UITextField`:

```
import SwiftUI

/// Shows a list of inspiring quotes/bio
struct FeatureView: View {

    private let emailTextField = CustomWrappedTextField(customPlaceholder: "Email")
    private let instagramTextField = CustomWrappedTextField(customPlaceholder: "Instagram name")

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Get Featured").font(.largeTitle).bold()
                    Spacer()
                    Text("1. Submit your information below")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("2. On the 1st and 14th we choose a new account to feature")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("3. Get notified by e-mail if your account is chosen!")
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 20, bottom: 0, trailing: 20))

            VStack {
                emailTextField
                instagramTextField
            }
        }
    }
}

final class CustomWrappedTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewType = UITextField

    let customPlaceholder: String

    init(customPlaceholder: String) {
        self.customPlaceholder = customPlaceholder
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {

        let customTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 320, width: 300.00, height: 30.00))

        customTextField.placeholder = customPlaceholder

        return customTextField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {

    }
}
```